# How To Asynchronously Retrieve Web-Service-Based Master Page Content in MVC3

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous, master-pages, parent-child

I'm developing an application that uses a parent controller class and a common Master page to make hundreds of database configuration fields available to multiple child controllers (like a "wrapper" class). I'm adding an external web service/feed that will also be used by all child controllers. It will read content from an XML, text or HTML file on a remote web server and use it on the Master page that is being shared by all Views (i.e. common content to all pages coming from an external source). However, I need to use an asynchronous pipeline to handle the request so that it's not tying up server threads waiting for calls to these remote web services.

Is there a way I can use MVC's AsyncController to accomplish this? I understand how it works in a simple scenario where I have a basic controller and a couple of Action Results. But this application has about 20 different Action methods in various controllers, and I really don't want to have to split all of them up into "Async" and "Completed" methods, especially since the retrieved data is only being displayed on the common Master page. Is there something I can implement at the "parent" controller level so that it's inherited by all the child controllers, or only in the Master page itself?